# How to properly override virtual method to add functionality?

Tags: c++, qt, oop, polymorphism

In base class I have simple remove by id virtual function, however in derived class I need also emit a signal (notify) after removing.

In base class. Below is the default implementation of function

```
void Ui::GameEntityList::remove_games_by_sport_id_virt(const QString &sport_id)
{
    for(QList<GameEntity*>::iterator it = m_game_list.begin();
        it != m_game_list.end();)
    {
        GameEntity* tmp = (*it);
        if(tmp->get_sport_id() == sport_id)
        {
            it = m_game_list.erase(it);
            delete tmp;
            tmp = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            ++it;
        }
    }
}
```

In derived class. Overriding

```
void Ui::GameWidgetList::remove_games_by_sport_id_virt(const QString &id)
{
    QList<GameEntity*>::iterator it;
    for(it = m_game_list.begin(); it != m_game_list.end();)
    {
        GameWidget* tmp = dynamic_cast<GameWidget*>(*it);
        Q_ASSERT(tmp != NULL);
        if(tmp->get_sport_id() == id)
        {
            it = m_game_list.erase(it);
            emit remove_game_in_monitor(tmp->get_id(),     this->get_monitor_number()); // need to emit this signal
            delete tmp;
            tmp = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            ++it;
        }
    }
    this->set_number_of_games(m_game_list.size()); // need to call this function
}
```

I can't manage a way to avoid code duplication. Should I have an empty virtual notify() function and call it after removing an element? That way I can override notify() in derived to do the job. Is that an acceptable decision? Is implementing remove by id in base class unnecessary?

Comment: does `get_id()` only belong to `GameWidget`? why are you dynamic casting?

Comment: @dwcanillas I guess, that `GameEntity` derives from `GameWidget`.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek just because one is derived from the other doesn't mean he needs to cast.

Comment: He needs to, because he performs downcasting.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek he doesn't need to downcast if the cast isn't providing anything useful.  If all the methods he is calling here are virtual or accessible from the base class, there is no need to cast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, it is not that bad regarding amount of duplicated code. But, anyway, in situations like this, you may want to make this function non-virtual and move this customizable functionality to other virtual functions:

```
class GameEntityList
{
private:
    virtual void on_erase(GameWidget* w)
    {
        //empty
    }

    virtual void on_finish(GameWidget* w)
    {
        //empty
    }

    //others
};

class GameWidgetList : public GameEntityList
{
private:
    virtual void on_erase(GameWidget* w)
    {
        remove_game_in_monitor(w->get_id(), this->get_monitor_number());
    }

    virtual void on_finish(GameWidget* w)
    {
        this->set_number_of_games(m_game_list.size());
    }

    //others
};
```

And then:

```
void Ui::GameEntityList::remove_games_by_sport_id_virt(const QString &id)
{
    QList<GameEntity*>::iterator it;
    for(it = m_game_list.begin(); it != m_game_list.end();)
    {
        if(tmp->get_sport_id() == id)
        {
            it = m_game_list.erase(it);

            this->on_erase(tmp); //customizable

            delete tmp;
            tmp = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            ++it;
        }
    }

    this->on_finish(); //customizable
}
```

Comment: you can remove the dynamic cast and Q_ASSERT

Comment: @dwcanillas I'm providing answer to the question, not reviewing OP's code.

Comment: and combining the two methods into a solution that works well is part of your answer.  the cast and assert weren't a problem until you combined the functions.

Comment: Ah, yes, my bad, thought I was copying body of `remove_games_by_sport_id_virt()` from `GameEntity`. Fixed, thanks!